# Convert lucene query string to lucene query

Tags: java, solr, lucene

How can I convert lucene query string like +(tel:+777) to lucene Query object in programmatically way?

I had solr query: q="+777" after converting to lucene query I got +(tel:+777) and converted to lucene query string.

Comment: what do you wanna achieve? just for understanding or do you wanna rebuild this query in lucene?

Comment: I want to save lucene queries in file and after load them from file to Lucene Query objects. I need it for my custom percolator.

Answer (score 0):

You convert a query string to a Query object by parsing it.

```
Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);
```

Be careful of the reverse though. `Query.toString()` is not designed for serialization, and may not output a query that accurately represents that query to a parser, or is parseable at all.

Comment: You can't do this because you will get error due to + in term. (Encountered "+"...). I tried this way already.

Comment: Right, because that isn't valid query syntax. As I said, toString is not designed to serialize queries. `Query` is not serializable. If you want to do this you will have to come up with your own serialization strategy.

Comment: It is my question How can I do it? I thought maybe it exists in lucene already.